# How is it possible to have null defernce if null is checked before

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have this function that searches an element in a skip list. I don't understand the error given by address sanitaizer:

```
==5461==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000010 (pc 0x555555555e28 bp 0x7fffffffdeb0 sp 0x7fffffffde90 T0)
==5461==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==5461==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x555555555e28 in search_skip_list (/home/matteo/Scrivania/Algo/laboratorio-algoritmi-2021-2022-main/Esercizio 2/ex2/build/main+0x1e28)
    #1 0x5555555556fb in main (/home/matteo/Scrivania/Algo/laboratorio-algoritmi-2021-2022-main/Esercizio 2/ex2/build/main+0x16fb)
    #2 0x7ffff73c3d8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #3 0x7ffff73c3e3f in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:392
    #4 0x5555555552e4 in _start (/home/matteo/Scrivania/Algo/laboratorio-algoritmi-2021-2022-main/Esercizio 2/ex2/build/main+0x12e4)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/home/matteo/Scrivania/Algo/laboratorio-algoritmi-2021-2022-main/Esercizio 2/ex2/build/main+0x1e28) in search_skip_list
==5461==ABORTING
[Inferior 1 (process 5461) exited with code 01]
```

There is a segmentation fault that I don't catch in my code. I'm new in C and I don't know how to use gdb correctly to find the problem. I put here the funtion and the way the structure are inizialized, full code is too long and the items are take by a file.

```
void* search_skip_list(SkipList *list, void* item){
    if(list == NULL || item == NULL ) return NULL;

    Node *x = list->head;
    
    for (int i = list->max_level-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {   
        while (x->next[i]!=NULL && strcmp(item,x->next[i]->item) < 0)
        {
           x = x->next[i];
        }  
     }
    x = x->next[0];

    if(strcmp(item,x->item) == 0) return x->item;
    else{
        return "failure";
    } 
}
```

```
struct _SkipList {
    Node *head;
    unsigned int max_level;
    int (*compare)(void*, void*);
};
struct _Node {
    Node **next;
    unsigned int size;
    void *item;
};
```

```
SkipList* create_skip_list(){
    SkipList *list = malloc(sizeof(SkipList));
    list->max_level = 0;
    list->compare = NULL;
    list->head = create_head_node(NULL,MAX_HEIGHT);
    return list;
}
```

```
Node* create_head_node(void* item, int level){
    if(level <1)
        return NULL;

    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(node == NULL){
        printf("error malloc node\r\n");
        /* Returning here prevent the program from accessing non allocated
         * memory. */
        return NULL;
    }

    node->item = item;
    node->size = level;

    node->next = (Node**)malloc(level * sizeof(Node *));
    if (!node->next) {
        printf("error malloc node next\r\n");
        free(node);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        node->next[i] = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}
```

I find out that could be a deference of a NULL pointer but I don't understand how is it possible.But i think is strange cause I check first of all if there is NULL value. There is other problem that could give this error? How can I use correctly GBD to find the exactly row where the problem is?

I run gdb with a breakpoint before the function and seems to stop the first time it enter in the function, as if the first element is NULL and deference to a NULL pointer.

**EDIT:** i changed the create_head_node as the answer but still have the same problem.

**EDIT:** this is the print modified search function given in the answer

```
 node=0x603000000130   item=attuava

 node=0x6030000001c0   item=diguazzata

 node=0x603000000220   item=negativi
 node=0x603000000160   item=riconfessa

 node=0x603000000100   item=riparleremo

 node=0x6030000001f0   item=sparente

 node=0x6030000000d0   item=taglino
item: 0x563ae2c3e0c0
x: 0x603000000070
i: 3
x->next[3]: 0x603000000160
x->next[3]->item: 0x60c000000340
x: 0x603000000160
i: 2
i: 1
x->next[1]: 0x6030000001f0
x->next[1]->item: 0x60c0000004c0
x: 0x6030000001f0
i: 0
x->next[0]: 0x6030000000d0
x->next[0]->item: 0x60c000000100
x: 0x6030000000d0
x: 0x6030000000d0
x: (nil)
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==9041==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000010 (pc 0x563ae2c3df03 bp 0x7ffd25e1f260 sp 0x7ffd25e1f240 T0)
==9041==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==9041==Hint: address points to the zero page.
```

Comment: What if `x->next[i]->item` is NULL?

Comment: - or `list->head`?

Comment: I'm quite sure this is already wrong:
`Node *x = malloc(sizeof(Node)); x = list->head;
`
Why would you create a Node/allocate memory if you right away overwrite the pointer. This is at least a memory leak. Then in the following code list->head can of course be null_ptr, as can be x, that you have just assigned to exactly this pointer.

Comment: `` Node *x = malloc(sizeof(Node)); x = list->head;   was a try, with integer value work with a simple Node* x=list->head

Comment: The report leads off with "SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000010".  `0x000000000010` very likely is indeed an invalid address for the program, but it very likely *does not* correspond to a null pointer.  It looks like the result of having performed some arithmetic on a null pointer (which has undefined behavior, but is unlikely in practice to produce a segfault).

Comment: `x->next[i]->item` and `list->head` cannot be null i think

Comment: @JohnBollinger maybe with i compare a string that is NULL??

Comment: You are destroying your list via `free(x);` and incosistently not setting `list->head->next[0]` to null_ptr.
And how is this supposed to work at all? `free(x); if(strcmp(item,x->item) == 0) return x->item;`  -  First delete the memory, afterwards dereference it?

Comment: If you compile with debug info, then address sanitizer could show you the exact line where the problem happened.

Comment: @André It was a refuse of old version

Comment: Ok, I see your edits now. With `node->next = (Node**)malloc(level * sizeof(Node));` you alloc the wrong type. You want to alloc `sizeof(Node*)`. But if I count correctly you are allocating more memory than you need, so rather another memory leak then the source of your SEGFAULT.

Comment: @André  i need an array of pointer. The structure given as request has Node**....is not correct to allocate in this way? (Node**)malloc(level * sizeof(Node));

Comment: @Matteo: No, you have to allocate for a pointer: `node->next = (Node**)malloc(level * sizeof(Node*));` But as said, this should not have caused the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent memory access error, I advise you to rewrite your function this way:

```
Node* create_head_node(void* item, int level){
    if(level <1)
        return NULL;

    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(node == NULL){
        printf("error malloc node\r\n");
        /* Returning here prevent the program from accessing non allocated
         * memory. */
        return NULL;
    }

    node->item = item;
    node->size = level;

    node->next = (Node**)malloc(level * sizeof(Node *));
    if (!node->next) {
        printf("error malloc node next\r\n");
        free(node);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        node->next[i] = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}
```

Let's summarize what has changed in this snipped code:

- the function returns `NULL` if it has not successfully allocated the  `node`. As compared to what you have in your question, in case of allocation failure you still do access the non allocated memory and setup `item` and `size` entries.
- the function checks the allocation status of the `next` array. In case it has failed, it frees the previously allocated memory and stops here by returning `NULL`.
- `next` being an array of `Node *`, the data type has been set accordingly in the `malloc` function.

NOTE:

You also use `strcmp` to compare the two `void *`. If you want to compare array of `char` then you may want to cast those to `char *` to help read your code. Otherwise, since `strcmp` stops upon the first `NULL` byte, you should rather use `memcmp` and specify the size of the memory to compare.

EDIT:

Can you give the result of this slightly edited code so that we can see how it goes?

```
void* search_skip_list(SkipList *list, void* item){
    if(list == NULL || item == NULL ) return NULL;

    Node *x = list->head;
    if (!x) {
        printf("x is NULL\r\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("item: %p\r\n", item);
    printf("x: %p\r\n", x);

    for (int i = list->max_level-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("i: %d\r\n", i);

        while (x->next[i]!=NULL && strcmp(item, x->next[i]->item) < 0) {
            printf("x->next[%d]: %p\r\n", i, x->next[%d]);
            printf("x->next[%d]->item: %p\r\n", i, x->next[i]->item);

            x = x->next[i];
            printf("x: %p\r\n", x);
        }
    }
    printf("x: %p\r\n", x);

    x = x->next[0];
    printf("x: %p\r\n", x);

    if(strcmp(item,x->item) == 0) return x->item;
    else return "failure";
}
```

EDIT:

As per the details you provided based on my request, I understand your issue.

At the very end of the loop, you override `x` with `x = x->next[0];`. However, upon this last assignment `x` gets `NULL` (cf. the last print of the value of `x`). As per your structure definition, `item` is at offset `0x10`. So accessing the value of `item` starting from `0` goes to `0x000000000010`. There goes the error triggered by Valgrind \o/

Comment: I would always discourage from using `goto` in C++ and this code still has the wrong size in the allocation here: `node->next = (Node**)malloc(level * sizeof(Node));`

Comment: @André Indeed, in this case, the goto can be changed to directly free previously allocated right in place. Usually, this is the only case I use the goto so that I don't have to repeat "free" of previous resources. I also fixed the size of the malloc-ed data type.

Comment: I don't know if goto can be used in C too. But i don't think the problem is create_node cause if it's it, the insertion would not work too...(another function that insert item in the list but it works)

Comment: I changed the algorithm like this cause i understsnd the problem but this not solve the AddresSanitaizer error...still point to a zero page

Comment: @Jib i use strcmp in this case temporally. Cause the requires specifies tha the function has to accept generic item that will be compared by the specific function setted in skipList. For now is like a placeholder so the function can't know that has to compare 2 string....but maybe when i will write the funtion i'll need to cast too, right?

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello can you test with the modified version of `skip ...` ? The cast is for clarity. To me, when reading the code, there was no point in using `strcmp` against a `void *` unless you know for sure it is a `char *`.

Comment: I tried and this in the edit is the result. The problem is that x has a pointer to nil??

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello I updated the answer to explain what is going on..

Comment: Seems to be wrong the search while cause point always at the last element that need the next field to null

Comment: Ok thanks to help me to solve the problem. The item to compare was switched so in the given request pdf there was an error. This gave segmentation fault cause always return the last element and is next(NULL). But now is strange cause i find the right value and strcmp is euqual to null but function return "failure"

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello If you now have issue(s) with the algorithm I suggest you open a new question where you give more details regarding you problem (your needs, what you have done vs. expected).